# about the gcd in arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist

input 2 integers
eg x=18 ,y=30
do prime factorization and save each prime factor in arraylist
and find gcd and lcm in two arraylist

i tried to find gcd,it result {2,3,3}
but i need {2,3}
so i can do the 2*3

```
    public static int gcd(ArrayList<Integer> A,ArrayList<Integer> B)
    {
        int sum1=1;
        A.retainAll(B);
        
        for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++)
        {
            sum1*=A.get(i);
        }
        return sum1;
    }
    
    public static int lcm(ArrayList<Integer> A,ArrayList<Integer> B)
    {
        int sum = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++)
        {
            sum*=A.get(i);
            
        }
        for(int j=0;j<B.size();j++)
            {
                sum*=B.get(j);
                
            }
        return sum/gcd(A,B);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println(gcd(A(x),B(y)));
        System.out.println(lcm(A(x),B(y)));
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your method of prime factorization?

Comment: @NowhereMan public static ArrayList<Integer> A(int x)
 {
  ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for(int i=2;i<=x;i++)
  {
   while(x%i==0)
   {
    x/=i;
    A.add(i);
   }
  }
  return A;
 }
 
 public static ArrayList<Integer> B(int y)
 {
  ArrayList<Integer> B = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for(int i=2;i<=y;i++)
  {
   while(y%i==0)
   {
    y/=i;
    B.add(i);
   }
   
  }
  return B;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the factorization methods `A` and `B` are identical, so only one of these methods should be kept and used.

Second, in order to calculate the greatest common divisor using the prime factors, `List::retainAll` is not appropriate because:

1. it does not handle duplicate entries properly.
2. it modifies list `A` implicitly.

A proper intersection can be computed with the help of a frequency map for each factor:
for `x = 18` and `A = [2, 3, 3]` and `y = 30` and `B = [2, 3, 5]` the intersection is `[2, 3] -> gcd = 6`:

```java
public static int gcd(List<Integer> A, List<Integer> B) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> common = new HashMap<>();

    A.forEach(a -> common.merge(a, 1, Integer::sum));

    int gcd = 1;
    
    for (Integer b : B) {
        if (common.merge(b, -1, Integer::sum) >= 0) {
            gcd *= b;
        }
    }
    return gcd;
}
```

It is also worth to note that here list `A` is not affected.

So for the test:

```java
int x = 18;
int y = 30;

ArrayList<Integer> A = A(x);
ArrayList<Integer> B = A(y);
System.out.println("gcd = " + gcd(A, B)); // gcd = 6
System.out.println("lcm = " + lcm(A, B)); // lcm = 90
```